# What could have caused g++ (and clang++) executables to stop working?

Tags: executable, c++

I can't understand what's going on. Yesterday everything was working normally. Literally all I did since then was clearing the bash history with `history -cw`. Today all I get when trying to execute my g++-compiled programs is complete void:

[image: ???]

The same code works perfectly fine when compiled on another machine. I can't even think of how to search for the reason! This is very bizarre, I don't understand how this could happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong direction on your slash.  Use `/` instead:

```
[rinkaru@localhost ~]$ ./6.out
```

Comment: Oh well...I guess that's what you get when you are a newbie and clear command history...

Comment: But there should have been an error message.